# Finding pattern for prime numbers

Tags: trigonometry, prime-numbers

I was trying to find pattern for prime numbers. I find applying $\sin(\frac{x}{p})$ where $p$ is prime number, acts as applying sieve. Then I formulated a function:

$y=\sin(x)\csc(\frac{x}{2})\csc(\frac{x}{3})\csc(\frac{x}{5})...\csc(\frac{x}{p})$ for any $p$ belonging to prime number.

Interestingly all the roots are prime number multiplied by pi.

Could anyone help me to find out a common formula to find out the roots?

Answer (score 3):

You're not finding any pattern in the primes numbers. I'm not sure how you get from $\sin(\frac{x}{p})$ to your $y$, I assume your $y$ involves $\sin(\frac{x}{p})$ in the numerator  in some form. Then of course, you will find roots at every prime. The function $\sin x$ is $0$ whenever $x$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$. So the function $\sin(\frac{x}{p})$, where $p$ is prime, is $0$ whenever $\frac{x}{p}$ is an odd multiple of $p$. So suppose the odd number was $2k+1$. Then we have $\frac{x}{p}= (2k+1) \pi$ then $x= (2k+1)p \pi$ as the roots.

For your function $y$,
$$
y= \dfrac{\sin x}{\sin(\frac{x}{2}) \sin(\frac{x}{3}) \sin(\frac{x}{5}) \cdots \sin(\frac{x}{p})}
$$
for some collection of primes. But this will be $0$ whenever $\sin x$ is $0$ (except possibly at $x=0$, where you have $0/0$, so that requires more analysis), which as above, is the odd multiples of primes. But because all primes (except $2$) are odd, of course, $y$ will be $0$ at all the prime multiples of $\pi$. But so too will it be at every odd number. Really you can replace 'prime' with *any* 'special' number, e.g. even, square, 'every 5th integer', etc and the same will be true because of the properties of $\sin x$.

So what you are really observing is the periodicity of $\sin x$, not any property of the primes.

*EDIT.* Something I glossed over is the issue of $0/0$. This will happen when in $y$ the denominator is also $0$ which happens at some multiples of $\pi$. For instance, at $x=6\pi$, the numerator and denominator are both $0$ so there are issues. But in any case, the function $y$ is not defined there, and it's certainly not the case that this is a root for $y$. So it is still the case that a 'prime' is a root.

Comment: Do you mean the roots won't be primes?

Comment: @JohnyRoyan I'm not even sure which function you are talking about, because as I said, there does seem to be a connection between $\sin(x/p)$ and your $y$. But in either case, no, the roots are not prime.